# Is there a maximum frequency at which hysteresis appears?

Tags: quantum-spin, ferromagnetism, low-temperature-physics

If a ferromagnetic material is immersed in an alternating magnetic field at frequency $\omega$, the material will follow a hysteresis cycle at that frequency. But if that frequency is high enough, the spins will oscillate more and more, and I think it will somehow increase the temperature of the material (because in a classical picture: more frequency $\Rightarrow$ more velocity $\Rightarrow$ more kinetic energy $\Rightarrow$ more temperature.)

As hysteresis only appear below the Curie temperature, if higher frequencies make the metal get hotter, there will be a critical frequency $\omega_c$, above which hysteresis won't appear. Does such frequency exists for every ferromagnetic material?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the frequency, the hysteresis loss depends on the strength of the magnetic field, which is reflected in the Steinmetz's equation:

$P_V=kf^aB_{max}^b$,

where $P_V$ is power loss per unit volume, f - frequency, $B_{max}$ - peak magnetic field, $k$, $a$ and $b$ - Steinmetz's coefficients, which depend on the material.

So, even if we could heat ferromagnetic material to its Curie point through the hysteresis loss, the frequency at which it would occur would not be unique or characteristic for this material.